# RecycleView No adapter attached

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

Recently i am working on RecycleView nad Retrofit for Json practise.
I have managed everything but when i run my app it crushed and shows that no adapter attached.

This is my **MainActivity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
public MyRecycleViewAdapter adapter;
public RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<Movie> movies;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager llm= new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

    ApiINterface apiINterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiINterface.class);
    Call<Movies> call = apiINterface.getSongList("just_added");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Movies>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Movies> call, Response<Movies> response) {

           movies = response.body().getMovies();

            adapter = new MyRecycleViewAdapter(MainActivity.this , movies);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Movies> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}}
```

And this is my **Logcat:**

```
 06-14 17:05:21.16125804-25804/com.example.lolipop.retrofitexamplewithhindisong E/RecyclerView:
    No adapter attached; skipping layout 06-14 17:05:21.331 25804-25804/com.example.lolipop.retrofitexamplewithhindisong E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    06-14 17:05:21.371 25804-25804/com.example.lolipop.retrofitexamplewithhindisong E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                                 at com.example.lolipop.retrofitexamplewithhindisong.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:45) at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What's the problem i can't find.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: why this question will duplicate this is about RecycleView Adapter problem and you tag that is null point problem @Ironman

Comment: did you check if `response.body().getMovies();` is not returning null value ?

Comment: Also check if `onFailure` is being called instead of `onResponse`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout)

Comment: Tip: if you click MainActivity.java:45 on the logcat at the first line under null pointer exception it would show you the exact line which causes the error. Do that and show that exact line using a comment. The line should be inside the onResponse() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `response.body().getMovies()` returning null.
Better to check for null -

```
if(response.body() != null && response.body().getMovies() != null && response.body().getMovies().size()> 0){
adapter = new MyRecycleViewAdapter(MainActivity.this , movies);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```